# Short story, part of a collection, involving a clown pun duel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I believe this was a book of collected stories focusing on a planet that developed its society based on a stranded circus troupe. I vaguely remember that there were wizards (stage magicians using trickery), acrobats, showgirls, and clowns, at the least, as kind of guilds in the society. The particular story that I recall had two clowns meeting for battle, and it turns out to be all about puns with the other looking physically shaken by a blow with each pun uttered.

Unfortunately, the details have largely escaped me other than that one involved a clown saying that his uncle had fallen into a bad vat of dye, but came out alright because "[only the good dye stunned](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/only+the+good+die+young)" (I have a vague idea that this pun was either what took the other fellow out, or that it was a particularly weak pun that preceded his defeat). If I recall correctly, it was very much a "young gunslinger takes on the veteran" feel, and I think the veteran clown won. My vague memories is that the narrative involved someone from off-world interacting with the people on the planet, providing an excuse for everything to be explained to the reader.

I read this somewhere in the early 1990s in a hardback book from the local library (the book is probably long gone given how much wear they tended to incur) and I think the cover showed a poster of a circus clown with a lizard crawling out of the clown's eye.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This has got to be a tale from one of the Circus World books (*Circus World*, *City of Baraboo*, and *Elephant Song*) by [Barry B. Longyear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_B._Longyear#Circus_World_series).

It's most likely Circus World, an anthology that includes the short story [Dueling Clowns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circus_World_(novel)).

From Goodreads:

> From the mind of the Nebula and Hugo award-winning author of Enemy
> Mine, comes a planet of dreamers, mimes, acrobats and magicians.
>
> Two hundred years earlier, a circus starship is stranded on the Planet
> Momus. Recently discovered by the rest of the galaxy, the population
> of Momus-the remaining descendants of the original circus-must deal
> with interstellar power politics and war, and they do so in their own
> special way in Circus World.

From a copy of *[Circus World](https://archive.org/details/circusworld0000long/page/116/mode/2up)* on the Internet Archive:

> ... Spaht tried to rally, but Kamera scented blood. 'My... nephew lost consciousness and fell into a vat of stain...'
>
> "'The good dye stunned.' Spaht fell to all fours and began crawling out of town...

[image: The cover of “Circus World.”]

Comment: Probably the one with this cover? http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/6/63/CRCSWRLD7E1980.jpg

Comment: Ah! And I found the line in question in the Internet Archive copy.

Comment: And that is the cover I remember. :-D Of course, I misremembered the positioning of the lizards on the clown.

Comment: I have been trying to think of who wrote this series for 10+ years! (Somehow I thought it was a very early Orson Scott Card series ...)